# Masstransit: How to republish or send negative acknowledgement?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, microservices, masstransit

I have multiple microservices. They communicate through message broker as currently, I am using Masstransit rabbitmq. Things are working fine.

Now, I have a case where one service A publishes a message and another service B consumes it. Service B sends a number of emails which takes some time. If it fails, it invokes a new event where I want to send a negative acknowledgment and want service A to republish again after some delay. I know I can through an exception in service B consume method but this is not possible here. Send email runs in an independent way. How can I republish the message from service A to B?

Comment: When A publishes it's message to B, have it include a key that B can use later on to send a message back to A, which also includes an status value, then A uses that key to look-up the earlier message and uses the status value to determine whether to remove it from it's recent history queue, or resend it to B.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question has nothing to do with MassTransit, or any other library, which you can use to support the flow. You need to design the message flow according to your needs.

It is not very clear, why sending an email takes some time, and why it can fail, so the following is purely based on assumptions.

If service B sends a batch of emails by consuming a single message, it is not transactional. If it sends 100 emails and fails on 101, what would happen? If you have a message retry policy, it will send the first 100 emails again.

I would definitely try to limit a single message scope to handle a single transaction. Split each email send operation to its own message and handle those (potentially thousands) of messages, it's totally fine. At least, in case of a retry, it will retry one operation only. Each individual operation is confirmed, not the whole batch. It is fine for service A to command service B to send a number of emails. It is the responsibility of service B to split the number of emails it needs to send to a number of individual messages. Service B can perfectly send messages to itself.

How you handle errors is your own decision. For all the cases when I had to deal with sending emails, it was like this:

- Each email is a separate message
- If it fails, I check what the reason is. Usually, you don't get a failure from the mail provider immediately, unless the email address is obviously incorrect, or the provider itself is down.
- Prevent sending a message to wrong emails in the first place, you don't need to overload the system with such obvious errors.
- If the email provider is down, engage the message retry policy accordingly. Ensure to have a circuit breaker in place to manage the backpressure from the provider if you hammer it too hard and get rate-limited. You can also rate-limit your own consumers. All of those are built-in middleware in MassTransit.
- Only retry transient errors. If the error is permanent, there's no need to retry.
- If all the retries suddenly fail, you can still engage the redelivery. It's built-in to MassTransit. Still, ask yourself a question why can it even happen?
- Sending a NACK message from service A to service B is trivial. If the error happens, instead of throwing, publish or send another message for service A. I don't see any issue with that.
- You can always check if your retry or redelivery count is depleting by looking at the consumer context metadata. You can decide to only send a NACK message to service A if all the retries have failed.
- There's nothing wrong with throwing per se, as you get the retry and redelivery middleware there to help you handling transient failures. Service A can always listen to Fault events if those policies exhaust their retry counts and the message will land in the poison queue. The poison queue is valuable as it allows you to analyse the nature of the failiure.

Again, it's not a technical issue. You need to decide how you want to handle this workflow. MassTransit would help you to implement it in the way you want it, but you first need to decide what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.